# How to avoid initial large number evaluation in LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, logarithmic-scale

If you run this:

```
LogLogPlot[Echo[x], {x, 10000, 100000}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

You will see the first evaluation point is at a very very large number  `E^10000`, way outside the plot domain:

[image]

But the problem I'm running into is that my function is such that the larger the input, the more time it takes to complete evaluation.  Therefore, for most of my real cases, the plotting never completes.

How do I tell `LogLogPlot` not to try to plug in numbers way outside the domain of the plot?

Comment: Why use `Echo`??  This has nothing to do with plotting the variable.

Comment: It indicates what values of x are being plugged in, right?

Comment: Exactly.  Why would you need to use `Echo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why `E^10000` is evaluated first. I'd say this might be a bug and might be worthwhile to be reported to Wolfram Support.

Here a workaround: You can write a wrapper for your function so that it gets evaluated only if arguments with the correct size are submitted.

```
ClearAll[f];
a = 10000;
b = 100000;
f[x_?(a < # < b &)] := x
LogLogPlot[Echo[f[x]], {x, a, b}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```